# Identify the structure of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3,3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I assume that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3)\simeq\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]$. Thus we should have $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]/(3)$? That would be smaller than $\mathbb{Z}_3[i\sqrt{3}]$ because $3\in(i\sqrt{3})$? If so, what would be such a ring?

Would there be more straight-forward approach?

Comment: Hint: first mod out the $3$.

Comment: This is exercise 10.4.2. of Artin, M. (1991) "Algebra"

Comment: @Magdiragdag Simply $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3,3)\simeq Z_3/(x^2+3)$? If so, what would be $Z_3/(x^2+3)$? How can I mod out $Z_3$ with $(x^2+3)$? Sorry I am quite a beginner.

Comment: @taro You'd get ${\mathbb Z}_3[x]/(x^2+3)$, which equals ${\mathbb Z}_3[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Is that correct that $\mathbb{Z}/(x^2)\simeq \{a_0 + a_1 x; a_0, a_1\in \mathbb{Z} \}$? Then I can say at the end that $\mathbb{Z}/(x^2+3,3)\simeq \{a_0 + a_1 x; a_0, a_1\in Z_3\}$?

Comment: $(x^2+3,3) \subset (x^2,3)$ is clear. $(x^2+3,3)\supset (x^2,3)$ because $(x^2+3) - 3 = X^2$. $\supset$ was not clear for me.

Comment: The problem with writing $\{ a_0 + a_1 x ; a_0, a_1 \in {\mathbb Z}_3\}$ is that that set is not a ring. It is true that every element of ${\mathbb Z}_3[x]/(x^2)$ can be uniquely represented by an element of that set.

Comment: Or I could write it something like ${R}'=\{a+bx \pmod{x^2+3};a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_3\}$? In this clear to see it is closed under addition and multiplication (multiplication because $(x^2+3)=0$ in ${R}'$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say that it is "smaller" than  $\mathbb{Z}_3[\sqrt{3}i]$, the question that remains rather is what is $\mathbb{Z}_3[\sqrt{3}i]$  exactly?

We adjoin an element $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2 = -3$, but this is $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. This structure is thus formed by  elements $a + b \alpha$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_3$. Thus with additive structure only  it is $\mathbb{Z}_3^2$.

Since $\alpha^2=0$, it cannot be a field as it has zero-divisors. Thus it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ with coordinatewise operations as a ring too.

A possibly somewhat cleaner and in any case more common way to see this is as proposed in comments the other way round first observe the isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2+3)$. Yet then $x^2+3 = x^2$ and we are essentially in the same situation as before. (Note we take a quotient with respect to a polynomial that is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ thus the result is not a domain.)

Comment: Multiplication isn't _quite_ componentwise (although with a change of basis, that can surely be fixed). See that $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,ad+bc)$.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was silly of me. I'll fix it soon (but not can't right away).