# Determine the structure of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3,5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My thought is:

$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3,5)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2+3)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_5[\sqrt{3}i]$. The structure of $\mathbb{Z}_5[\sqrt3i]$ is additively $\{a+3b+c\sqrt3i\}$, where  $a, b, c\in\mathbb{Z}_5$. However, since $3\mathbb{Z}_5$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{15}\subset\mathbb{Z}_3$, we have $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3,5)\simeq\{a+b\sqrt3i; a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_5\}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_5$. Would this be correct?

If so, we should have $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3,5)\simeq\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2,5)$. It sounds wrong, but I don't know what is actually wrong (or if this is correct). Is there a method for simplifying $(x^2+m,n)$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+m,n)$ and why?

Comment: This is exercise 10.4.2. of Artin, M. (1991) "Algebra". Related post is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915062/identify-the-structure-of-mathbbzx-x23-3?noredirect=1#comment3935001_1915062).

Comment: Fro the last half of my question, I got a better idea from the [Harvard "Abstract Algebra" lecture 27](http://wayback.archive-it.org/3671/20150528171650/http://oli.extension.harvard.edu/mathe222/2008/fall/lectures/math-e222-L27-20031119.mov?download). It explains adjoining an element $\alpha$ to a ring, R, by the construction: $R[\alpha]$, which is actually isomophic to $R/(p(x))$ where p(x)'s coefficients are in R.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+3,5\rangle\cong\left(\Bbb Z[x]/\langle 5\right)/\left(\langle x^2+3,5\rangle\right)\cong\Bbb F_5[x]/\langle x^2+3\rangle\cong\Bbb F_{5^2=25}$$

First isomorphism: this is just the second or third isomorphism theorem for rings

Second isomorphism: Because $\;\phi:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb F_5[x]\;,\;\;\phi(f(x)):=f(x)\pmod5\;$ is a rings homomorphism with kernel $\;\langle 5\rangle\le\Bbb Z[x]\;$

Third homomorphism: because $\;x^2+3\;$ is irreducible over $\;\Bbb F_5[x]\;$ and its degree is two.